# Drupal modules be used without Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

Problem, can I use Drupal modules in my own PHP application? ( without setting up Drupal ). I searched a bit, there seems to be .zip file for the module, init where there are .inc files.

Is it possible to use this without setting up Drupal ?

I need to configure Solr search, Drupal seems to have a search API and thought I could use it.

Comment: No you won't be able to use the search API module without Drupal, it's very tightly coupled

Comment: Thank you @Clive, looks like I'll have to use Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP solr library, instead of trying to hitting your brain on drupal modules files. With few extra code you can able to do indexing, searching ,etc. There is a good library https://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/ .

There is a good tutorial on Solr installation and usage in PHP. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-apachesolr/

Comment: I'm stuck at "Search Suggestions" mate, I've configured an instance of Solr to do the basic searches. Since Drupal has used "Did you mean" feature I thought I could use that through Drupal in someway, so I dont have to spend a lot of time into it ( I tried to configure the Solr suggester, but didn't give the result I wanted ). If you have any idea on that would be nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use Drupal modules anywhere outside from Drupal.

But, you can download the modules, and extract the main php functionality to make it work with your business requirements.

Some modules have also open frameworks that can help you.

Hope that this helps.